# Error with Padlen in signal.filtfilt in Python

Tags: python, numpy, filter, scipy, signal-processing

I am working with library "scipy.signal" in Python and I have the next code:

```
from scipy import signal

b = [ 0.001016    0.00507999  0.01015998  0.01015998  0.00507999  0.001016  ]

a = [ 1.         -3.0820186   4.04351697 -2.76126457  0.97291013 -0.14063199]
data = [[ 1.]
[ 1.]
[ 1.]
...]
# length = 264
y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
```

But when I execute the code I get the next error message:

```
The length of the input vector x must be at least padlen, which is 18.
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `data` is a two-dimensional array with shape (264, 1).  By default, `filtfilt` filters along the last axis of the input array, so in your case it is trying to filter along an axis where the length of the data is 1, which is not long enough for the default padding method.

I assume you meant to interpret `data` as a one-dimensional array.  You can add the argument `axis=0`

```
y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=0)
```

to filter along the first dimension (i.e. down the column), in which case the output `y` will also have shape (264, 1).  Alternatively, you can convert the input to a one-dimensional array by flattening it with `np.ravel(data)` or by using indexing to select the first (and only) column, `data[:, 0]`.  (The latter will only work if `data` is, in fact, a numpy array and not a list of lists.)  E.g.

```
y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, np.ravel(data))
```

In that case, the output `y` will also be a one-dimensional array, with shape (264,).

Comment: `numpy.squeeze(data)` also works if the other dimension size is one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a two-dimensional array with shape (264, 2), you can also use `np.hsplit()` to split `data` into two separate arrays like so:

```
import numpy as np

arr1, arr2 = np.hsplit(data,2)
```

You can view the shape of each individual array, for example:

```
print(arr1.shape)
```

Your code will then look something like this:

```
y1 = signal.filtfilt(b, a, arr1)
y2 = signal.filtfilt(b, a, arr2)
```